# abstract algebra question with p-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H<G$ a subgroup. Suppose that $H$ is a $p$-group, $p$ a prime, and $p\mid[G:H]$. Show that $p\mid[N_G(H):H]$ and $H<N_G(H)$. In particular, if $G$ is a $p$-group and $H<G$, then $H<N_G(H)$.

I think I will have to use the $3$rd Sylow Theorem, but do not know how to do it specifically. Can someone give an idea?

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Set $\Omega=\{xHx^{-1}|x\in G\}$. You can see easily that $G$ acts on $\Omega$. You should try to follow the following steps:

1.Since $|\Omega|=[G:N_G(H)]$, we have two cases $|\Omega|>1$ and $|\Omega|=1$.

2.If $|\Omega|>1$, then put $\Delta=\Omega-\{H\}$ and so $H$ acts on $\Delta$ by conjugation.

3. There is $x\in G$ such that for every $h\in H$, $xhx^{-1}\in N_G(H)$ and so $h\in N_G(x^{-1}Hx)$.
4. Switch $x^{-1}Hx$ by $H$ in $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $[G:N_G(H)][N_G(H):H]=[G:H]$. Then either $p$ divides $[G:N_G(H)]$ or $p$ divides $[N_G(H):H]$.  First suppose the former case is true and derive a contradiction.

Edit: fixed mistake.  sorry about that.

Comment: The first case is hard to see , as we trivially have $\;H\le N_G(H)\;$ , so $\;[H:N_G(H)]\;$ could not even be well defined.